# If I make an array of abstract objects, can I put different types of children in the same array?

Tags: java, arrays, object, abstract

For example:

```
abstract class Shape { 
    public abstract void move();
}

class Circle extends Shape { ... }
class Square extends Shape { ... } 

...

Shape[] shapes = new Shape[10];
shapes[0] = new Circle();
shapes[1] = new Square();

...

for (Shape i: shapes) 
    i.move();
```

etc.

I tried doing this and it seems okay in theory, but I keep getting an unknown error when I try to run it ("Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem"). Also before running it, it gives me these weird error warnings: "{ expected after this token." I double checked and all my brackets are fine. Should I just use an interface instead or something?

**EDIT:** I fixed it, but it still makes absolutely no sense to me. The error was in the line:

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[2];
shapes[0] = new Circle();
shapes[1] = new Square();
```

I changed it to this:

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[2];
{
shapes[0] = new Circle();
shapes[1] = new Square();
}
```

And suddenly it works. What?

**EDIT 2:** Nevermind me. I initialized the arrays outside of a method.

Comment: Could you show the real code, rather than - `...`? Perhaps you're having those array assignments outside any method.

Comment: You're probably right, I assigned the arrays in the class body. Whoops!

Comment: Yep, you're writing your code outside of a method. Your "fix" is creating an initializer block, which most certainly isn't what you want. Figure out which method this code should go in and put it there. (That may involve making a new method.)

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a "feature" where you can run code which doesn't compile.  I highly recommend you not use this as it only delays finding bugs (which maximises the cost of fixing them)

When you turn this feature off you will find the line of code which is not compiling and it might not have anything to do with the use of sub-classes.

In short, you can do this, the error is probably something unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a variable outside a method (at class level) is permitted only at declaration.

So you can call this outside a method:

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[2];
```

But you cannot call this outside a method:

```
shapes[0] = new Circle();
shapes[1] = new Square();
```